# 'last' method not returning last item in array in RSpec test - Rails4 Ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, acts-as-list

Was working on an RSpec test that copies @protocol to @dest and saw this:

```
[26] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> @protocol.step_items.count
=> 3
[27] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> assigns(:dest).step_items.count
=> 3
[28] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> @protocol.step_items[2].note
=> "note3"
[29] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> assigns(:dest).step_items[2].note
=> "note3"
[30] displayed an instance variable.  Removed for berevity  
[31] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> @protocol.step_items.last.note
=> "note3"
[32] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> assigns(:dest).step_items.last.note
=> "note2"
[33] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)> assigns(:dest).step_items.last.last?
=> false
[34] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ProtocolsController::ProtocolCopy>)>
```

pastebin of the pry session [may be easier to read here](http://pastebin.com/52ZxuMMU).

My [gemfile is here](http://pastebin.com/8vZtiw3r).

Seems `assigns(:dest).step_items.last` is returning the second-to-last item in the array.

Result is reproducible.  Looks like a bug to me.  Is this some odd RSpec side effect?  Is this somehow related to my use of acts_as_list?  Either way, it seems like a wrong result for 'last'.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see some SQL queries generated (if there are any). If there aren't, then I'd say it's probably not `acts_as_list`. If you'd like more help with the `aal` aspect, post your model with your call to `acts_as_list`.